# Why does metasploit still work?

Tags: penetration-test, metasploit, patching

Metasploit is publicly available as well as all the exploits and the vulnerabilities in its database. This means that a company can patch and secure its network and software accordingly to the metasploit database thus renders metasploit useless.

How can metasploit still hack?

Comment: Because companies don't consistently patch their networks against all the exploits supported by Metasploit.

Comment: Metasploit is a _framework_. It's very common to use it to design your own exploits or your own payloads. Furthermore, it's often used in legal penetration testing, where the fact that it is detectable does not always matter.

Comment: If everyone drives safely, why do we need car insurance?

Comment: @forest and the fact that it is detectable in predictable ways means it has a built-in method where you can identify an potentially authorised test from an unauthorised one.

Answer (score 12):

If a company were to actually patch all their systems, then Metasploit would have very little to offer in that environment.  However, it's *extremely* common for companies not to patch all of their systems for any of a number of reasons:

1. Bad inventory management -- some companies don't even know all the systems they have
2. 3rd party software that's only certified for old software
3. A belief that patching leads to instability/crashes/unacceptable downtime
4. Understaffed or underskilled IT department
5. Human error
6. Mistaken beliefs about security ("We have a firewall, why do we need to patch?")

There's probably other reasons I'm forgetting right now.  Even before the availability of Metasploit, there's resources like Exploit-DB that list exploits and vulnerabilities.  Companies didn't patch then either.

Look at all the other questions tagged [patching](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patching) for more insight into how patching is not a trivial problem.

Comment: True that. I'd add lack of resources to the list, or bad deployment platforms that makes patching more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

Metasploit is not just about the exploit modules but also the scanners, the database to connect various other tools (Nexpose, nmap, Nessus, etc.) into a single pane, and the meterpreter. (Metasploit Pro adds many more benefits, including team coordination).

Metasploit exploits are also useful to help an organisation *quantify and understand the risks* of a vulnerability. Not all systems can be patched, and sometimes alternate protections need to be put in place. Metasploit versions of the exploits help to condense the risk into a concise and easy-to-understand form.

Comment: Metasploit Pro also adds an updated obfuscation framework that effectively evades AV (unlike, say, shikata_ga_nai).